# Finding the tangent line of $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and $2x^2 + 5y^2 = 10$

Tags: derivatives

If line $y = kx + n$ is a common tangent of circle : $x^2 + y^2 = 4$ and ellipse: $2x^2 + 5y^2 = 10$, then $k^2 + n^2$ is equal to?

I've tried doing this task by equalizing derivatives of circle and ellipse functions, but it doesn't seem right to me, and I get the x value but I don't know what to do with it? Can somebody explain me what steps I should make and give me the hint to solution?

Answer (score 1):

To compute the intersection of the circle and the tangent line we get:
$$x^2+(kx+n)^2=4.$$
This becomes
$$(k^2+1)x^2+2knx+n^2-4=0.$$
For tangency this should have equal roots, which means the discriminant must be $0$. Consequently
\begin{align*}
(kn)^2-(k^2+1)(n^2-4)&=0\\ 
4k^2-n^2+4&=0. 
\end{align*}

Likewise do the same with ellipse. To get
$$5k^2-n^2+2=0.$$
Now you can compute $n^2+k^2$.